# Slurm can't run more than one sbatch task

Tags: linux, slurm

I've installed Slurm on a 2-node cluster.  Both nodes are compute nodes, one is the controller also.  I am able to successfully run `srun` with multiple jobs at once.  I am running GPU jobs and have confirmed I can get multiple jobs running on multiple GPUs with srun, up to the number of GPUs in the systems.

However, when I try running sbatch with the same test file, it will only run one batch job, and it only runs on the compute node which is also the controller.  The others fail, with an ExitCode of 1:0 in the `sacct` summary.  If I try forcing it to run on the compute node that's not the controller, it won't run and shows the 1:0 exit code.  However, just using srun will run on any compute node.

I've made sure the /etc/slurm/slurm.conf files are correct with the specs of the machines.  Here is the sbatch .job file I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=tf_test1
#SBATCH --output=/storage/test.out
#SBATCH --error=/storage/test.err
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2000
##SBATCH --mem=10gb
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
~/anaconda3/bin/python /storage/tf_test.py
```

Maybe there is some limitation with sbatch I don't know about?

Comment: Don't downvote and vote to close without a comment at least.  I'm stuck with Slurm and need help running batch jobs.  What should I do to improve the post?

Comment: Maybe you could check the output of the job. Both, standard and error outputs.

Comment: It wasn't even creating the output and error files.  Just giving me the very uninformative error codes.

Answer (score 1):

`sbatch` creates a job allocation and launches what is called the 'batch step'. 
If you aren't familiar with what a job step is, I recommend this page: https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html

The batch step runs the script passed to it from `sbatch`. The only way to launch additional job steps is to invoke `srun` inside the batch step. In your case, it would be

```
srun ~/anaconda3/bin/python /storage/tf_test.py
```

This will create a job step running `tf_test.py` on each task in the allocation. Note that while the command is the same as when you run `srun` directly, it detects that is inside an allocation via environment variables from `sbatch`. You can split up the allocation into multiple job steps by running `srun` with flags like `-n[num tasks]` instead. ie

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
srun --ntasks=1 something.py
srun --ntasks=1 somethingelse.py
```

I don't know if you're having any other problems because you didn't post any other error messages or logs.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't think about the log files and this is probably the key piece of info that will help.  https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#lbAK

Comment: By the way, I don't see 'batch step' anywhere in the quickstart, so I'm not sure what it is.  I do see 'job step' many times.  From [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/scancel.html) it says the batch step is "the shell script" (and maybe its child processes?).

It does seem to say that sbatch should have srun in it.  Maybe that's my problem?  I think I tried that and it made no difference.

Comment: In order to use the whole allocation, you do have to use srun in your script. So if you tried that and it didn't work, then you have another problem. I guess understanding the batch step is a bit more advanced, but the basic idea is that your script has to launch job steps with srun.

Answer (score 1):

If using `srun` on the second node works and using `sbatch` with the submission script you mention fails without any output written, the most probable reason would be that `/storage` does not exist, or is not writable by the user, on the second node.

The `slurmd` logs on the second node should be explicit about this. The default location is `/var/log/slurm/slurmd.log`, but check the output of `scontrol show config| grep Log` for  definitive information.

Another probable cause that lead to the same behaviour would be that the user is not defined or has a different UID on the second node (but then `srun` would fail too)

Answer (score 0):

@damienfrancois answer was closest and maybe even correct.  After making sure the /storage location was available on all nodes, things run with `sbatch`.  The biggest issue was the /storage location is shared via NFS, but it was read-only for the compute nodes.  This had to be changed in /etc/exports to look more like:

`/storage *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)`

Before it was ro...

The job file I have that works is also a bit different.  Here is the current .job file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1      # nodes requested
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --output=/storage/test.out
#SBATCH --error=/storage/test.err
#SBATCH --time=2-00:00
#SBATCH --mem=36000
#SBATCH --qos=normal
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=$USER@nothing.com
#SBATCH --gres=gpu
srun ~/anaconda3/bin/python /storage/tf_test.py
```